# Remove preceding numbers/symbols from a string

Tags: php, numbers, substring

I'm trying to write a function in PHP that finds the first letter in a string and then returns the remainder of the string.  So, for example, if you had a string:

"8932? Test 14 String"

The function would return

"Test 14 String"

I have written the following function that seems to do the job:

```
    function removenums($withnums) {

            $letters = str_split($withnums);
            $position = 0;
            foreach($letters as $letter) {
                    if(preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/",$letter)) {
                            break;
                    }
                    $position++;
            }

            $withoutnums = substr($withnums,$position);
            return $withoutnums;
    }
```

However, I'm just learning PHP and for the sake of education and I was wondering if someone with more experience might have a better solution.  All responses are appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `strpos` with `substr`

```
echo substr($string,strpos($string,'?')+1);
```

And you are ready to go

Please notice you should avoid whenever possibile `preg_*` functions because they are generally slower than the simpler `str*` functions

### After reading your comment

```
echo preg_replace( '/^[^a-z]+/i','',$string );
```

Comment: Assuming that the OP's input always has a question mark preceding the text he wants, your suggestion almost is right -- but it looks like in the provided example you pick up an extra space.

Comment: Yes, this is a good solution, but the input will not always have a question mark before the text

Comment: You need to tell us exactly how it could be all possibile format. We arent magic

Comment: Sorry, the string could have any possible combination of numbers/symbols before the first letter.  The function should strip any of these preceding numbers/symbols.

Comment: @Kurties: Read my answer, I have added the solution you need. If this helped you please think to mark this as the answer. Thanks

Comment: That's perfect!  Thanks!  I think it will have to be edited a bit to remove common symbols (such as the question mark) as well, but that's just what I was looking for.

Comment: Answer returns `est 14 String`. See my answer below (which was posted several minutes before his preg_replace suggestion).

Comment: @web: right. fixed it needed the /i. And actually I posted it 16 min earlier than you. (I didn't even nothing there was another answer)

Comment: @web: i am giving you +1 but believe me I didn't even read your answer.

Comment: @yes: no worries. You were probably editing your answer as I was posting. +1 to you as well.

Answer (score 1):

> finds the first letter in a string and
>   then returns the remainder

```
function removenums($withnums)
{
    return preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z]+/', '', $withnums);
}

echo removenums('8932? Test 14 String');
// output: Test 14 String
```